# I want to make my order summary page responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I created a thanks page for my e-commerce web app (Groovy and Grails) the code of my page is below I used bootstrap classes.

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <h3>Thank you for your Order!</h3>
                <br/>
                <br/>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <h5>Your Order Number is : 123456</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        // some backend code
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br/>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="btnOrderSummary">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-left float-none" 
                         style="margin: 5px">
                              View Order Summary
                          <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i></a>

                        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right float-none"
                                style="margin: 5px"> Home
                          <i class="fa fa-home "></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now whenever I see my page in responsive view suppose iPhone x

[image]

What Changes Should I make to CSS or bootstrap to make it responsive for all mobile devices?

Comment: share your ```CSS``` so   to understand your problem.

Comment: Hoping you have added proper bootstrap files as when i checked your code its worked fine and properly aligned. here is a guide from
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="btnOrderSummary">
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-left float-none">
          View Order Summary
      <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i></a>

    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right float-none"> Home
      <i class="fa fa-home "></i></a>
  </div>
```

remove `style="margin: 5px"` this inline css from both the buttons.

and add a media query to your css

```
@media(max-width:375px){
   #btnOrderSummary{padding:0;}
}
```

You can change max-width according to your need.

Comment: This is not what he is actually looking for.

Comment: @Nishant I think he wants to make his buttons responsive on smaller devices. And the answer I posted does the same.

Comment: first you don't mention media query I guess.

Comment: @Aman exactly. I thought I misunderstood and read the question again. Then I realized Nishant is the one with a misunderstanding.

Comment: no now it's correct when you insert ```media query```  now I upvote your answer bcz now it's working

Comment: @Nishant okay, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @media works i add more css to it according to my requirement
As i am new to css i always in backend development handling css is tough for me